# change background-image opacitiy in sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove transparency from the background-image of a section used in a web paged based on twitter bootstrap css but I can't see how to do that.

I have tried

```
.section{
  opacity:1;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `img { opacity: 1; }` try referring to your image inside your section

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes

```
    .section:after {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged for review due to its length/content. You should add a note about what is different in your answer, or why it should work better than what the OP already tried. Try to make this an opportunity for others to learn, not just to get the code working.